# Web API Concurrancy Issue : Static web methods migrated to Per Request web api controllers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, autofac, iis-8

**Application** : Asp.net with static web methods declared on page migrated to  asp.net web forms with static web methods converted to web API 2 controllers and secured using JWT tokens. Currently web API controller instantiation is done by AutoFac

```
 builder.RegisterType<Controller>().As<IController>().InstancePerRequest();
```

**Calling Code** : Javascript using async AJAX

**Problem** : Whenever more than 3-4 calls come for same web API in one second, requests are struck in IIS queue and take couple of minutes to ease off. This causes major issue to end users. Following is the data extracted from IIS logs.

**Analysis** : Its very hard for me to believe that Autofac is unable to create multiple instances per second of a controller. Web API is a very mature framework and there is a very little overhead in object instantiation. In earlier implementation static webmethods were shared with everyone so there was no instantiation overhead however with WebAPI there is a controller instantiation overhead which as per me AutoFac is unable to spin out instances in a second. I can change InstancePerRequest to Application scope but considering the problem is happening in production, it will be risky.

**Has someone faced such issues and any help that i can get from the vast experience that exists on SO. Also is this the right direction to analyse?**

I am planning to get a DebugDiag hang analysis done to confirm this.

[image]

Comment: Before assigning blame to Autofac.. What is in your controller constructors? What are your controllers doing? If you run your analysis on a minimal WebAPI project do you get the same "Autofac" results?

Comment: Also, shouldn't Autofac register your controllers for you? Is `IController` a custom interface or `System.Web.Mvc.IController`?

Comment: ControllerConstructors are very lean. IController is a custom interface. I will try to run the same on a minimal WebAPI project..

Comment: You really need to get some actual profiler data before you can determine what's causing the hangup.